# Use of 'it' and 'that' in affirmative replies

Tags: meaning

Could you please explain the reason for the difference in use between "it" and "that?"

Example:

> A.  *Is your name Jim?  B. Yes, it is.*

We can't say "Yes, that is". Why not?

> B.  *Is your name Jim?  B. Yes, that's right, it is.*

We can't say "Yes, it's right".  Why not?

Comment: Some UK dialects replace "it" with "that", per your example A, e.g. in East Anglia.

Answer (score 0):

We use "*that's*" when we need to show something far away (singular thing) but we use 'it' for for time/day/weather/Animal/baby/Country (in singular case) etc.

We can use 'That' before noun but we can't use 'it' before a noun. Like:

> 1. That book under the table is mine.
> 2. It is my book under the table.

Actually "That" is a demonstrative pronoun and we use it to demonstrate something. In your first sentence you can't use that because it's not demonstrating but in your second sentence you demonstrate it using 'right'.

Answer (score 0):

The situation's a bit more complicated than this, but the reason for the use of *it* in example A is that it refers to the noun phrase *your name*. The word *that* refers to the whole assumption *your name is Jim*, which is implied by the question.